# How to know if $Ax=b$ is consistent for all possible $b$ for any $m\times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

My textbooks says that for any $m\times n$ matrix it has $Ax=b$ is consistent for every possible $b$ as long as it has a pivot on every row.

Here is what I understand by that:

**MEANING OF THE QUESTION:
By the rules of matrix multiplication $b$ lives in $\mathbb R^m$ so that means spanning all possible $b$ is spanning all of $\mathbb R^m$. Also the number of pivots = number of linearly independent rows/columns.**

In nxn matrices:
At most there are $n$ linearly independent columns/rows and $b$ lives in $\mathbb R^n$ so IT'S POSSIBLE

In $m\times n$ matrices where $m < n$:
At most there can be $m$ linearly independent columns/rows and $b $ lives in $\mathbb R^m$ so IT'S POSSIBLE

In $m\times n$ matrices where $m > n$:
At most there can be n linearly independent columns/rows and $b$ lives in$\mathbb  R^m$, my vectors only span up to $\mathbb R^n$ which is a subset of $\mathbb R^m$ so IT'S NOT POSSIBLE.

Is my understanding correct, is there anything I am misunderstanding something? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, but is the statement for m>n true? Because I asked chatGPT and it told me somewhat mixed answers. I think that is my biggest doubt

Comment: Your statement is not quite correct, because you think $\Bbb R^n$ sits inside $\Bbb R^m$ in some particular way. But if $m>n$, the row space  cannot be $m$-dimensional.

Comment: Just replace " my vectors only span up to R^n" with " my vectors only span  a subspace of dimension at most $n$" and it becomes correct. And chatGPT is wellknown for being nonsensical in maths (at least).

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand, the vectors do not span R^n specifically. For example in a 3x2 matrix with linearly independent columns the vectors do not span specificallythe xy plane but they do form some plane in 3d space.

Comment: Ted, when you say the rows space cannot be m-dimensional, does this imply that my column space also cannot be m-dimensional right? so Ax=b cannot have solutions for every possible b.

Comment: Right. It’s hard to know how you think about $Ax=b$ being consistent — do you think about echelon form of the augmented matrix or do you think about the column space? Of course, with enough theory it’s all equivalent.